# Canadian citizen traveling to USA on British Passport using ESTA

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm traveling to the United States at the end of February to visit friends & family. I'm a Canadian citizen, however I do not have a Canadian Passport and will be traveling using my British Passport using ESTA. I spent 21 days in the USA in 2014 & 90 days in 2015 (1 short Trip, 1 long trip).

I'm only asking, because in my previous trip I tried to stay for 2 and a half months and the Border Officer pulled me aside. He went through my bags and looked at my travel history. He requested that I shorten my trip as my current trip would put me over 90 days in total (he counted my previous trip of about 25 days). That being said, when I asked about 90 day "reset" per trip, he said that rule didn't exist and it was 90 days per year.

Everything I've read online about the Visa Waiver Program contradicts what the officer said.

How do I protect myself when I visit again for 2 weeks at the end of Feb? Should I bring bank statements, letter of employment, etc?

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html

"Citizens of VWP countries* who reside in Mexico, Canada, or a nearby island are generally exempted from the requirement to show onward travel to another country* when entering the United States."

Comment: Well, do you reside (ie live in) in Canada, Mexico or a nearby island?

Comment: @CMaster I do. However the officer was aware of this fact previously and made no attempt to contest the fact.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not getting and using a Canadian passport? That would make it much easier, no visa required at all.

Comment: The 90 days per year thing is not right, I think you had bad luck. A British friend of mine has a home in Honolulu and spends about 6 months there (in aggregate) every year. I was astonished to learn that he has been entering on an ESTA (and before that an I-94) many times per year no problem for the last fifteen years. He says immigration doesn't care as long as he doesn't derive any income from US sources, and no individual stay exceeds 90 days.

Comment: Was your previous trip to the US, then Canada (or other neighbouring country), then back to the US? In that case, the time spent in Canada (or other neighbouring country) counts towards the 90-day limit. You need to exit North America altogether to start a new 90-day allowance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visa Wavier traveling to USA from Canada](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/visa-wavier-traveling-to-usa-from-canada)

Comment: @Calchas why is that astonishing?

Comment: @phoog I was under the impression that an ESTA was for infrequent short visits, not maintaining a residence

Comment: @jcaron The rule you describe does not apply to residents of Canada.

Comment: @Calchas If you look at the official information on the visa waiver program, there is no mention of frequency, only that each stay must be no longer than 90 days and that you must not be using the program to reside in the US.  It seems that spending a cumulative six months does not constitute residence in the eyes of DHS.  Presumably the actual total just under half a year.

Comment: @phoog Ah I must have read unofficial information. He tells me that the each of the Canadian expat community who are "half resident" in HNL count the days religiously, but the British "half resident" expats seem to get an easy ride at immigration and no one seems to worry too much about the exact number of days. Considering how much trouble it is for some people to get into the US just once, it's very interesting to me anyway.

Comment: @Calchas day counting is usually a tax issue.  Canadians are allowed into the US visa free for 6 months, so as far as immigration is concerned they just have to leave by the date stamped in their passports.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory mention: An ESTA is just permission to get on a plane. It is the Visa Waiver Program that governs whether you get to enter the US and how long you get to stay.

I've also never heard of a 90 day per year rule for VWP visitors. 90 days per visit is usual. However (as you know) the clock doesn't normally reset for time spent in Canada. To not be caught by that rule you would have to provide evidence of your Canadian residency (I'm not sure if proof of Canadian citizenship would quality, since they are not necessarily the same thing). Canadian citizenship would normally exempt you from the terms of the VWP, but you may have to have a Canadian passport to qualify.

The issue is that VWP is supposed to be for 'short, occasional visits'. The CBP officer may have simply decided that having spent two and a half months in the US already you were trying to live in the US. He is entitled to refuse you entry if he believes that.

My advice: get a Canadian passport. I'm also a dual citizen living in Canada, and the Canadian passport gets you a lot of freedom to enter the US without fingerprinting and other hassle, and it gets you into Britain (and Europe) with as little hassle. The only advantage a UK passport gets you is to go in the fast line at Heathrow, which isn't nearly as useful.

Comment: ... at Heathrow and every other airport and many other ports of entry to any EU/EEA/Schengen country plus Switzerland, which is slightly more useful than just at Heathrow.  Plus the Canadian passport lets you spend six months in the US rather than 90 days.

Comment: The above comment is unfortunately no longer valid, since the UK is no longer an EU member. However, the British passport is still more useful (compared to a Canadian one) when visiting Ireland.

Of course, a Canadian passport is still far better for visiting the US than anything else (except for the US passport). If I were a Canadian citizen regularly visiting the US, I'd for sure get a Canadian passport.